# Exclude Styling on a subsequent list

Tags: css

I applied this code on an ordered list to make the decimal numbering bold

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: counter1;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: counter1;
}
ol li::marker {
  content: counter(counter1) ". ";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The problem is that it is also automatically applied to a subsequent list which should have different list style

```
ol ul li {
    list-style: lower-latin;
}
```

The question is, is there any way to only apply the bold styling to the main ol list while excluding all subsequent ol, ul lists?

Thanks

Comment: You could replace your code with `ol > li` to target `li` that are direct children of `ol`

Comment: You could set different classes to both lists and use them for styling.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 'Bold' styling is being applied to the subsequent lists is because you used the selector 'ol li' hence every 'li' element in 'ol' element would use the styling.
To prevent the happening you are recommended to give a class to elements you want to have the bold styling and then give styles on the class selector. Another option if you do not want to mess with the class is that you can code:

```
ol ul li:marker{
    list-style: lower-latin;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```